# Run time error 91: Object variable not set on CustomXMLnode

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to read some customXMLnodes from a customXMLpart using VBA to populate some content controls in Microsoft word.  For my code sample below I'm just printing the immediate window as I attempt to debug this issue.

I can do this when I read a customXMLnode that is inside of a customXMLpart that has no namespace.  However, when trying to read a node in a customXMLpart that has a namespace, I get

> run-time error 91 (object variable not set)

at the line where it attempts to output to the immediate window (see my comments in the code sample below).

I've set a breakpoint before this and it shows that the node (cxn in my code below) is set to Nothing.

The XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<People xmlns="people">
    <Person>
        <Name> bob </Name>
        <Street> Main St. </Street>
    </Person>
</People>`
```

The VBA is:

```
Dim cxp1 As CustomXMLParts
Dim cxn As CustomXMLNode

' Returns all of the custom xml parts with the given namespace.
Set cxp1 = ActiveDocument.CustomXMLParts.SelectByNamespace("people")

' Get the node matching the XPath expression.
Set cxn = cxp1(1).SelectSingleNode("/People/Person/Name")
'executing the line below gives me run-time error 91 (object variable not 
'set). And cxn shows that it is set to Nothing.  
Debug.Print cxn.Text
```

I got this code from a Microsoft website https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.customxmlparts.selectbynamespace and made some slight changes for my specific XML.

I know the XML is good because I can read it when there is no namespace when using VBA as follows:

```
Dim parts As CustomXMLParts
Dim part As CustomXMLPart

Dim nodes As CustomXMLNodes
Dim node As CustomXMLNode

Set parts = ActiveDocument.CustomXMLParts

For Each part In parts

    If Len(part.NamespaceURI) = 0 Then
        Set node = part.SelectSingleNode("/People/Person/Name")
        debug.Print = node.Text
```

EDIT:  This error is SOLVED.

To read a customXML part with a namespace the Xpath on the node must include the XML prefix.  This was confusing because I did not have a prefix but apparently MS Word assigns one.  Therefore you must obtain the prefix of the CustomXMLpart as a string variable and change the Xpath expression using that variable as follows:

```
Dim cxp1 As CustomXMLParts
Dim cxn As CustomXMLNode
Dim prefix As String

' Returns all of the custom xml parts with the given namespace.
Set cxp1 = ActiveDocument.CustomXMLParts.SelectByNamespace("people")
prefix = cxp1(1).NamespaceManager.LookupPrefix("people")

' Get the node matching the XPath expression using the prefix variable (even 
'if you don't explicitly set a prefix you must include a prefix)
Set cxn = cxp1(1).SelectSingleNode("/" & prefix & ":" & People & "/" & prefix & 
":" & Person & "/" & prefix & ":" & Name")
Debug.Print cxn.Text
```

Comment: This looks like a great source on how to deal with custom xml: [Reading CustomXML](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?37833-Solved-Reading-CustomXML&s=7ece984bf058e02c8bb59d1646ff5996&p=244846&viewfull=1#post244846)

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I did not get the answer from that website but I definitely appreciate you providing the resource.